# Determine which day event is on when event is selected in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

When an event is clicked, is there any way to determine which date this event falls on? Im running into this issue when dealing with events that span multiple days, and since the event only contains a start and end date, I have not found any way to ascertain which date of the multi-day event was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional fields into your JSON object when you bind up your events.

For example, I pass in a "leave" parameter that tells me whether an event is an appointment or a part of the day off.